# Haversine Distance Calc using Pandas Data Frame "cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>"

Tags: python, pandas, haversine

Im trying to use the Haversine calc on a Panda Dataframe.

```
from math import radians, cos, sin, asin, sqrt
    
def haversine(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2):
        
        # convert decimal degrees to radians 
        lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(radians, [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])
    
        # haversine formula 
        dlon = lon2 - lon1 
        dlat = lat2 - lat1 
        a = sin(dlat/2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon/2)**2
        c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a)) 
       
        r = 3956
        
        return c * r
```

This works when using the following code:

```
haversine(-73.9881286621093,40.7320289611816,-73.9901733398437,40.7566795349121)
```

However, when I use it against a Pandas DataFrame as  such:

```
train_data['Distance_Travelled'] = train_data.apply(lambda row: haversine(train_data['pickup_longitude'], train_data['pickup_latitude'], train_data['dropoff_longitude'], train_data['dropoff_latitude']), axis=1)
```

I get the following error.

```
"cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>"
```

I've tried numerous ways of casting but each attempt results in the same error.  I know that math is expecting float, but I don't understand why the Pandas series can't be cast as a float.

What edit needs to be made for it to work and why?

Comment: You need to use `row` instead of `train_data` in the call to `haversine` inside the lambda function.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! The littlest things can cause the biggest headaches.

Comment: Indeed. But look at the answer below - it is way more efficient than looping with `DataFrame.apply()`.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `apply` since it is not vectorized. Also, use the vectorized functions from numpy:

```
def haversine(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2):
    lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = np.deg2rad([lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])

    dlon = lon2 - lon1 
    dlat = lat2 - lat1 
    a = np.sin(dlat/2)**2 + np.cos(lat1) * np.cos(lat2) * np.sin(dlon/2)**2
    c = 2 * np.asin(np.sqrt(a)) 

    r = 3956

    return c * r

train_data['Distance_Travelled'] = haversine(train_data['pickup_longitude'], 
                                             train_data['pickup_latitude'], 
                                             train_data['dropoff_longitude'], 
                                             train_data['dropoff_latitude']
                                            )
```