# how to custom sort in pandas dataframe based on two columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, geolocation

I have a dataframe as :-

```
91745   52.087569   4.893148
430245  52.045561   4.948235
435274  52.031570   4.840220
437177  52.086108   4.883128
446128  52.091580   4.964827
453169  52.024054   4.869313
458566  52.168720   4.989130
473877  52.128700   4.968660
```

I have a tuple say x = (52.0878, 4.89323).  I want to calculate the distance between the x and (latitude,longitude) of the df and sort in increasing order.

In order to calculate the distance I would do

```
   df_lat_long = (45.7597, 4.8422) 
   x = (48.8567, 2.3508)
   distance = haversine(df_lat_long, x)
```

I want to sort the df by distance

Answer (score 1):

Use [sklearn's haversine](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.haversine_distances.html) to calculate the distance array, then `np.argsort` and `iloc`:

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import haversine

distance = haversine(df[['lat','lon']], x)

df.iloc[np.argsort(distance)]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am using scikit-learn==0.20.0 and unable to do import probably not available in the version. I also can not upgrade scikit-learn due to other reasons.  can something same be done using haversine ```from haversine import haversine``` or any different way?

Comment: sklearn's haversine is from 0.22.2. You can see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64270864/4238408) for an implementation that allows vectorization.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this:

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import haversine
df["distance"] = ""
df["distance"] = df.agg(lambda x: haversine((x["lat"],x["long"]), x), axis=1)
```

Comment: How is it different from my answer? Plus, you should not use `agg` in this case since sklearn's haversine is vectorized whereas your code isn't.