# Haversine Function using Pandas Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, haversine

I am new to Python. I am trying to calculate Haversine on a Panda Dataframe. I have 2 dataframes. Like this: [First 3 rows of first dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKEYS.png)

Second one: [First 3 rows of second dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oa52.png)

Here is my haversine function.

```
    from math import radians, cos, sin, asin, sqrt

    def haversine(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2):
      # convert decimal degrees to radians 
      lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(radians, [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])

      # haversine formula 
      dlon = lon2 - lon1 
      dlat = lat2 - lat1 
      a = sin(dlat/2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon/2)**2
      c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a)) 
      r = 3956 # Radius of earth in kilometers.
      return c * r
```

I took the longitude and latitude values in the first dataframe as centers and drew circles on the map (I took the Radius as 1000m). First, I try to give all the lon and lat values in the second dataframe to the haversine function with the lon and lat values in the first row in the first dataframe. Then I'll do the same for the other rows in the first dataframe. Thus, I will be able to find out whether the coordinates (longitude and latitude values) in the second dataframe are located in circles with central longitude and latitude values in the first dataframe. It works when i use like this:

```
a = haversine(29.023165,40.992752,28.844604,41.113586)
radius = 1.00 # in kilometer
if a <= radius:
    print('Inside the area')
else:
    print('Outside the area')
```

In the codes I wrote, I could not give the exact order I wanted. I mean I tried my code by giving all the lon and lat values ​​in the first dataframe and the second dataframe, but logically this is wrong (or unnecessary operation). I tried the below code (I tried the code [Haversine Distance Calc using Pandas Data Frame "cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64270707/haversine-distance-calc-using-pandas-data-frame-cannot-convert-the-series-to-c)) But it gives an error: ('LONGITUDE', 'occurred at index 0').

```
from math import radians, cos, sin, asin, sqrt

def haversine(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2):
    
    # convert decimal degrees to radians 
    lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(radians, [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])

    # haversine formula 
    dlon = lon2 - lon1 
    dlat = lat2 - lat1 
    a = sin(dlat/2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon/2)**2
    c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a)) 
    r = 3956 # Radius of earth in kilometers.
    return c * r

iskeleler.loc['density'] = iskeleler.apply(lambda row: haversine(iskeleler['lon'], iskeleler['lat'], row['LONGITUDE'], row['LATITUDE']), axis=1)
```

Can you help me with how I can do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Haversine Distance Calc using Pandas Data Frame "cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64270707/haversine-distance-calc-using-pandas-data-frame-cannot-convert-the-series-to-c)

Comment: @MustafaAydın I tried it. But it gives me another error. I updated and writed the code I tried again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you are using to calculate haversine distance receives one float in each argument, so indeed you need to pass floats for each argument. In this case `iskeleler['lon']` and `iskeleler['lat']` are Series.

This should work to calculate the distance between coordinates in the same row:

```
iskeleler.loc['density'] = iskeleler.apply(lambda row: haversine(
    row['lon'], row['lat'],
    row['LONGITUDE'], row['LATITUDE']
),axis=1)
```

But you are looking for a pair-wise distance which might require a `for` loop and this is not efficient. Try [sklearn.metrics.pairwise.haversine_distances](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.haversine_distances.html)

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import haversine_distances

distance_matrix = haversine_distances(
    iskeleler[['lat', 'lon']],
    iskeleler[['LATITUDE', 'LONGITUDE']]
)
```

If you prefer the table structure, then:

```
distance_table = pd.DataFrame(
    distance_matrix,
    index=pd.MultiIndex.from_frames(iskeleler[['lat', 'lon']]),
    columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_frames(iskeleler[['LATITUDE', 'LONGITUDE']]),
).stack([0, 1]).reset_index(name='distance')
```

This is an example, there are many ways to create the dataframe from the matrix.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I get the point. Pair-wise distance was my looking for. However the bottom code didn't work (table structure). It's not a big deal I can learn the ways you mentioned and try it again. Thanks again.

Comment: Can I ask something about haversine_distance? Is it true that give the latitude and longitude values into haversine_distances function? Or I've to convert these latitude and longitude values to radius and then give the radius to haversine_distances? I want to get values in km. I did it like this. I multiplied distance_matrix here by 6371. (6371: radius of earth in km). Then I thought I could find the values less than 1km. Is this true?

Comment: Inputs should be in radians, multiply output by 6371 to get results in km